# Rendering an array inside a collection in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a collection of decks, and each deck has a number of cards. 
The field "cards" is an array holding the IDs of the cards in the deck.

Problem is, I have a card list from which the user can choose cards to add to a deck. When the user chooses a card to add to the cards array inside Decks collection, Deps throws an exception saying "can't create second landmark in same branch" unless I don't use a partial to render the list, which is an issue for me since each card has its own events. Though the data is added properly to the deck since when I refresh the page, the updates appear.

Decks.js

```
Template.deckList.deck = () ->
  Decks.findOne(_id: Session.get "deck").cards
```

Deck-list.html

```
<template name="deckList">
    <section class="deck-list"><h1>deck</h1>
    <ul class="cards">
        {{#each deck}}
            {{> cardInList}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul></section>
</template>
```

Now I thought of making a separate collection to hold both IDs (card and deck), but that might not work for future collections with the same issues (hand for example in the game collection)

Thanks!

Comment: This question has been sponsored by [CodersClan](http://www.codersclan.net/ticket/120)! Get expert support for your personal code problems with bounties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but if I've understood you correctly you've got a bad design there. You don't want to have to update an array in the deck document every time you add/delete a card. It would be easier for you to leave out the `cards` field in the deck documents, and instead add a `deckId` field to the card documents. While MongoDB often encourages nested/embedded fields, Meteor Collections generally work far better with typical relational-database style schemas. Check out this approach to your problem:

**Decks.js**

```
Template.deckList.deck = () ->
  Decks.findOne( _id: Session.get "deck" )

Template.deckList.cards = () ->
  Cards.find( deckId: Session.get "deck" )
```

**Deck-list.html**

```
<template name="deckList">
  <section class="deck-list">
    <h1>{{#with deck}} {{title}} {{/with}} Deck</h1>
    <ul class="cards">
      {{#each cards}}
      {{> card }}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>

<template name="card">
  <li>{{foobar}}</li>
</template>
```

Using this approach, you can simply add/delete cards to/from your decks, and the changes will be automatically reflected in realtime without the need to update an additional document in another database collection.

EDIT: If you want a many-to-many collection instead of a one-to-many, you can modify the publish method on the server to return the cards for a particular deck, and avoid the need to publish that connection table to the client. It might look something like:

```
// Server publish method
// Return just cards that are in deck "deckId"
Meteor.publish('cards', function (deckId) {
    var cardIds = CardsDecks.find({ deckId: deckId }).map(function (connector) {
        return connector.cardId;
    });

    return Cards.find({ _id: {$in: cardIds } });
});

// Client subscribe method
Meteor.subscribe('cards', Session.get('currentDeckId')); // Get just the cards related to the current deck
```

Cheers!

**Note:** This was originally answered on [CodersClan](http://www.codersclan.net/ticket/120)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that Cards collection is static, I mean it doesn't update anything inside it. I might just go and use the many to many relationships and make another collection to hold the card Id and the deck id. Would that work well?

Comment: That could work, but that wouldn't be a great solution. What do you mean by "static"? If you're wanting another collection to hold the card and deck ids, presumably you have a card collection that this method would work perfectly with. You wouldn't have to change the cards more with this method than you would with another method involving a cards collection, this way just adds an extra field, while taking away all of the template iterating pain which would exist with another approach.

Comment: Also, unless one card can belong to many decks also, you probably don't want a many to many relationship :)

Comment: Actually, I do want a many to many relationship since a card can belong to many decks and a deck can have up to four copies of a certain card. I was just thinking of making that "deckId" field an array to accept multiple decks?

Comment: Ah. In that case, you probably do want a separate table like that. I would use the same approach I've outlined in the answer, but have the publish method on the server return just the cards valid for the deck you're currently viewing, based on that deckId/cardId collection.

Comment: Again, I have a list of cards on the right side (cards collection) and the deck on the left. Cards can be added by double-clicking/drag&drop. So I guess a separate table would be good enough for now. If I notice a very slow performance, then I might consider using other ways. Thanks again~

Comment: If you want a many to many relationship, another table is probably the best way to do that currently, yes :)